# VoiceOver not reading aria-label for links in iOS 10

Tags: ios, wai-aria, voiceover

VoiceOver is not reading aria-label for links. If the role is set to 'button' then it works. I could use 'title', which does work, but I that would require me to rewrite my code for links in my app. It did work in iOS 9.x, is there a work around for this?

Thx

Comment: Update your code for clarity.

Comment: <a href="#" aria-label="This page link">Skip</a>

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but it just popped up on my radar because it was modified today to have the `wai-aria` tag.

This problem was a real bug in iOS VoiceOver.  See https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=162578, but it was subsequently fixed in a couple .dot versions later.  It's working fine today with 12.1.4.

If, for some reason, there is a device still with iOS 10 and you need to work around the problem, you could use `aria-describedby` instead.  It wasn't broken.  The purpose of that attribute is slightly different from `aria-labelledby`, but it'd be a "good enough" hack for the time being.  But you'd have to go back and change `aria-describedby` back to `aria-labelledby` if the device was updated to a new iOS.