# iOS Voice Over Failed to Read Aria-Label

Tags: html, ios, accessibility, voiceover

iOS Voice Over does not read the `aria-label`. Chrome and Android are working fine. Here's the sample code:

```
<span aria-label="This is the aria-label text" class="c-glyph video-icon" role="link" tabindex="0"></span>
```

For iOS Voice Over, it only reads "link"

I saw from another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42477371/voiceover-not-reading-aria-label-for-links-in-ios-10?rq=1) that this is a bug on iOS for version iOS 10, but it should be working fine for iOS 12. However, my device is iOS 14. Is this a bug from iOS?

edit:

Here's a more complete code:

```
<div class="result_data">
     <div class="facet-type">
          <span>facet type value</span>
     </div>
     <h4>title text</h4>
     <div class="result_indicators">
          <span class="c-glyph" role="presentation"></span>
          <span aria-label="This is the aria-label text" class="c-glyph video-icon" role="link" tabindex="0"></span>
     </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: I tried using your example in a basic HTML mock-up page to test on iOS 15 but VoiceOver didn't pick up anything (probably because the span is empty). Can you please post a more complete code example so others can try to reproduce the issue?

Comment: @George I have edited the question and added a complete code. Please let me know if you can reproduce. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears to be screen reader specific.  Your example doesn't work with NVDA but **does** work with JAWS.  <kbd>TABBING</kbd> to the empty span with NVDA just says "blank" whereas JAWS reads the `aria-label`.  So NVDA and VoiceOver are acting similarly (although VoiceOver doesn't even let me navigate to the empty `<span>` by swiping right whereas NVDA let's me <kbd>TAB</kbd> to it).

If you inspect the `<span>` element's accessibility properties, it **does** have an accessible name and that name *should* be announced by all screen readers, but apparently both VoiceOver and NVDA have an issue if the `<span>` is empty.

Here is Chrome's version of the accessibility properties:

[image: Chrome accessibility properties]

The "Computed Properties" of "Name" is set to your `aria-label` and it even says that's where the name is coming from, so technically it should be announced.

The issue is because the `<span>` doesn't have any content.  A bug should be reported to Apple (for VoiceOver) and NVDA but in the meantime you can work around it by adding some "content" to the `<span>`.  Use `&nbsp;` if you don't want to see anything visual.

```
<span aria-label="This is the aria-label text" class="c-glyph video-icon" role="link" tabindex="0">&nbsp;</span>
```

(BTW, thanks for referring to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42477371/voiceover-not-reading-aria-label-for-links-in-ios-10?rq=1) I had answered a few years ago).

Comment: Interesting.. NVDA works for me on desktop..

Comment: thanks for the response. I will let you know if adding &nbsp; would work. Need to wait a few days for its deployment